# How to fix "Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in" WP

Tags: wordpress, updates

On my WordPress page I use the plugin `occupancy plan` "https://wordpress.org/plugins/occupancyplan/" after the update to PHP 7.3 wordpress gives the following error message:

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in
>   /homepages/XX/XXXXXXXXXX/htdocs/XXXXXXXXXX/wp-content/plugins/occupancyplan/[occupancy_plan_classes.php](https://github.com/wp-plugins/occupancyplan/blob/master/occupancy_plan_classes.php)
>   on line 4 - 38 and on line 620, 641, 657

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

it's probably a bit late but try adding this validation to every line with that error!

```
//fix issue with tax when it's not selected it
            IF(empty ($ variable name)){

                /*  null */
            }else{
                    $return = whatever was previously at the line
```

At the end you must to return something

```
}

    return floatval( $return );
```

Good Luck!